# XSL grouping issue

Tags: xml, xslt

I am  facing issue while grouping the elements its coming blank with no output. i want  to group all the shipments whose location name is same  say eg.

shipment PPGNA.00055396  and PPGNA.00055397 group together and  PPGNA.00055473 and PPGNA.00055472  separate as they are sharing same location name

below  is the  xml

xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <notify>
<Subject>Consolidated Tender Event Notification</Subject>
<Severity>Information</Severity>
<Contact ID="to">
    <FirstName>FXNL</FirstName>
    <LastName>TENDER</LastName>
    <Company>FEDEX NATIONAL (LTL) (FXNL)</Company>
    <LocationID>FXNL</LocationID>
    <Phone/>
    <Fax/>
           <Role/>
</Contact>
<contents>
    <content>
        <subject>PICKUP</subject>
        <shipment_gid>PPGNA.00055396</shipment_gid>
        <i_transaction_no>1693450</i_transaction_no>
        <tender_record>
            <bm_refnum>00055396</bm_refnum>
            <tender_status>PICKUP NOTIFICATION</tender_status>
            <response_time TZ="America/New_York">2015-06-02 19:19:28</response_time>
            <number_of_stops>2</number_of_stops>
            <total_weight IN="LB">9975.0</total_weight>
            <total_volume IN="CUFT">0.0</total_volume>
            <total_ship_unit_count>1</total_ship_unit_count>
            <stops>
                <stop>
                    <stop_num>2</stop_num>
                    <planned_arrival TZ="America/New_York">2015-05-26 12:00:00</planned_arrival>
                    <planned_departure TZ="America/New_York">2015-05-26 12:29:57</planned_departure>
                    <location_xid>FGL-03520000</location_xid>
                    <location_name>SHL</location_name>
                    <city>SHELBY</city>
                    <province/>
                    <province_code>NC</province_code>
                    <zip_code>28150</zip_code>
                    <country_code>US</country_code>
                </stop>
                <stop>
                    <stop_num>1</stop_num>
                    <planned_arrival TZ="America/Chicago">2015-05-21 13:00:00</planned_arrival>
                    <planned_departure TZ="America/Chicago">2015-05-21 13:29:57</planned_departure>
                    <location_xid>FGLSUP-11111113</location_xid>
                    <location_name>MOMENTIVE SPECIALTY CHEMICALS</location_name>
                    <city>BEDFORD PARK</city>
                    <province/>
                    <province_code>IL</province_code>
                    <zip_code>60501</zip_code>
                    <country_code>US</country_code>
                </stop>
            </stops>
            <start_time TZ="America/New_York">2015-05-21 13:00:00</start_time>
            <end_time TZ="America/Chicago">2015-05-26 12:29:57</end_time>
            <equipments>
                <equipment>
                    <equipment_xid>77661</equipment_xid>
                    <equipment_type_xid/>
                    <equipment_type_name/>
                    <equipment_group_xid>28RT_VAN_TEMPCONTROL</equipment_group_xid>
                    <equipment_group_name>28FT_TEMPCONTROL_VAN</equipment_group_name>
                </equipment>
            </equipments>
            <remarks>
                <remark>
                    <remark_qual_gid>LTL_SOURCE_ADDRESS</remark_qual_gid>
                    <remark_text>8600 WEST 71ST STREET</remark_text>
                </remark>
                <remark>
                    <remark_qual_gid>DELIVERY_INSTRUCTIONS_LINE_1</remark_qual_gid>
                    <remark_text>NONE</remark_text>
                </remark>
                <remark>
                    <remark_qual_gid>LTL_DEST_ADDRESS</remark_qual_gid>
                    <remark_text>940 WASHBURN SWITCH ROAD</remark_text>
                </remark>
                <remark>
                    <remark_qual_gid>LTL_TOTAL_PALLET_COUNT</remark_qual_gid>
                    <remark_text>0</remark_text>
                </remark>
            </remarks>
        </tender_record>

        <Type>TENDER</Type>
    </content>
    <content>
        <subject>PICKUP</subject>
        <shipment_gid>PPGNA.00055397</shipment_gid>
        <i_transaction_no>1693451</i_transaction_no>
        <tender_record>
            <bm_refnum>00055397</bm_refnum>
            <tender_status>PICKUP NOTIFICATION</tender_status>
            <response_time TZ="America/New_York">2015-06-02 19:19:52</response_time>
            <number_of_stops>2</number_of_stops>
            <total_weight IN="LB">9975.0</total_weight>
            <total_volume IN="CUFT">0.0</total_volume>
            <total_ship_unit_count>1</total_ship_unit_count>
            <stops>
                <stop>
                    <stop_num>1</stop_num>
                    <planned_arrival TZ="America/Chicago">2015-05-21 13:00:00</planned_arrival>
                    <planned_departure TZ="America/Chicago">2015-05-21 13:29:57</planned_departure>
                    <location_xid>FGLSUP-11111113</location_xid>
                    <location_name>MOMENTIVE SPECIALTY CHEMICALS</location_name>
                    <city>BEDFORD PARK</city>
                    <province/>
                    <province_code>IL</province_code>
                    <zip_code>60501</zip_code>
                    <country_code>US</country_code>
                </stop>
                <stop>
                    <stop_num>2</stop_num>
                    <planned_arrival TZ="America/New_York">2015-05-26 12:00:00</planned_arrival>
                    <planned_departure TZ="America/New_York">2015-05-26 12:29:57</planned_departure>
                    <location_xid>FGL-03520000</location_xid>
                    <location_name>SHL</location_name>
                    <city>SHELBY</city>
                    <province/>
                    <province_code>NC</province_code>
                    <zip_code>28150</zip_code>
                    <country_code>US</country_code>
                </stop>
            </stops>
            <start_time TZ="America/Chicago">2015-05-21 13:00:00</start_time>
            <end_time TZ="America/New_York">2015-05-26 12:29:57</end_time>
            <equipments>
                <equipment>
                    <equipment_xid>77662</equipment_xid>
                    <equipment_type_xid/>
                    <equipment_type_name/>
                    <equipment_group_xid>28RT_VAN_TEMPCONTROL</equipment_group_xid>
                    <equipment_group_name>28FT_TEMPCONTROL_VAN</equipment_group_name>
                </equipment>
            </equipments>
            <remarks>
                <remark>
                    <remark_qual_gid>LTL_SOURCE_ADDRESS</remark_qual_gid>
                    <remark_text>8600 WEST 71ST STREET</remark_text>
                </remark>
                <remark>
                    <remark_qual_gid>DELIVERY_INSTRUCTIONS_LINE_1</remark_qual_gid>
                    <remark_text>NONE</remark_text>
                </remark>
                <remark>
                    <remark_qual_gid>LTL_TOTAL_PALLET_COUNT</remark_qual_gid>
                    <remark_text>0</remark_text>
                </remark>
                <remark>
                    <remark_qual_gid>LTL_DEST_ADDRESS</remark_qual_gid>
                    <remark_text>940 WASHBURN SWITCH ROAD</remark_text>
                </remark>
            </remarks>
        </tender_record>

        <Type>TENDER</Type>
    </content>
    <content>
        <subject>PICKUP</subject>
        <shipment_gid>PPGNA.00055473</shipment_gid>
        <i_transaction_no>1693453</i_transaction_no>
        <tender_record>
            <bm_refnum>00055473</bm_refnum>
            <tender_status>PICKUP NOTIFICATION</tender_status>
            <response_time TZ="America/New_York">2015-06-02 19:21:10</response_time>
            <number_of_stops>2</number_of_stops>
            <total_weight IN="LB">8000.0</total_weight>
            <total_volume IN="CUFT">0.0</total_volume>
            <total_ship_unit_count>1</total_ship_unit_count>
            <stops>
                <stop>
                    <stop_num>1</stop_num>
                    <planned_arrival TZ="America/New_York">2015-05-28 09:22:45</planned_arrival>
                    <planned_departure TZ="America/New_York">2015-05-28 10:22:45</planned_departure>
                    <location_xid>PGL-0306</location_xid>
                    <location_name>WORKS 6 PPG INDUSTRIES INC.</location_name>
                    <city>CARLISLE</city>
                    <province/>
                    <province_code>PA</province_code>
                    <zip_code>17065</zip_code>
                    <country_code>US</country_code>
                </stop>
                <stop>
                    <stop_num>2</stop_num>
                    <planned_arrival TZ="America/New_York">2015-06-01 12:00:00</planned_arrival>
                    <planned_departure TZ="America/New_York">2015-06-01 12:00:00</planned_departure>
                    <location_xid>PGLSU-11111121</location_xid>
                    <location_name>MATERIAL SCIENCE</location_name>
                    <city>COLUMBUS</city>
                    <province/>
                    <province_code>OH</province_code>
                    <zip_code>43228</zip_code>
                    <country_code>US</country_code>
                </stop>
            </stops>
            <start_time TZ="America/New_York">2015-05-28 09:22:45</start_time>
            <end_time TZ="America/New_York">2015-06-01 12:00:00</end_time>
            <equipments>
                <equipment>
                    <equipment_xid>77849</equipment_xid>
                    <equipment_type_xid/>
                    <equipment_type_name/>
                    <equipment_group_xid>28CV_VAN</equipment_group_xid>
                    <equipment_group_name>28FT_VAN</equipment_group_name>
                </equipment>
            </equipments>
            <remarks>
                <remark>
                    <remark_qual_gid>DELIVERY_INSTRUCTIONS_LINE_1</remark_qual_gid>
                    <remark_text>NONE</remark_text>
                </remark>
                <remark>
                    <remark_qual_gid>LTL_SOURCE_ADDRESS</remark_qual_gid>
                    <remark_text>400 PARK DRIVE</remark_text>
                </remark>
                <remark>
                    <remark_qual_gid>LTL_DEST_ADDRESS</remark_qual_gid>
                    <remark_text>1660 Georgesville Rd</remark_text>
                </remark>
                <remark>
                    <remark_qual_gid>LTL_TOTAL_PALLET_COUNT</remark_qual_gid>
                    <remark_text>0</remark_text>
                </remark>
            </remarks>
        </tender_record>

        <Type>TENDER</Type>
    </content>
    <content>
        <subject>PICKUP</subject>
        <shipment_gid>PPGNA.00055472</shipment_gid>
        <i_transaction_no>1693455</i_transaction_no>
        <tender_record>
            <bm_refnum>00055472</bm_refnum>
            <tender_status>PICKUP NOTIFICATION</tender_status>
            <response_time TZ="America/New_York">2015-06-02 19:21:43</response_time>
            <number_of_stops>2</number_of_stops>
            <total_weight IN="LB">8000.0</total_weight>
            <total_volume IN="CUFT">0.0</total_volume>
            <total_ship_unit_count>1</total_ship_unit_count>
            <stops>
                <stop>
                    <stop_num>1</stop_num>
                    <planned_arrival TZ="America/New_York">2015-05-28 09:20:20</planned_arrival>
                    <planned_departure TZ="America/New_York">2015-05-28 10:20:20</planned_departure>
                    <location_xid>PGL-0306</location_xid>
                    <location_name>WORKS 6 PPG INDUSTRIES INC.</location_name>
                    <city>CARLISLE</city>
                    <province/>
                    <province_code>PA</province_code>
                    <zip_code>17065</zip_code>
                    <country_code>US</country_code>
                </stop>
                <stop>
                    <stop_num>2</stop_num>
                    <planned_arrival TZ="America/New_York">2015-06-01 12:00:00</planned_arrival>
                    <planned_departure TZ="America/New_York">2015-06-01 12:00:00</planned_departure>
                    <location_xid>PGLSU-11111121</location_xid>
                    <location_name>MATERIAL SCIENCE</location_name>
                    <city>COLUMBUS</city>
                    <province/>
                    <province_code>OH</province_code>
                    <zip_code>43228</zip_code>
                    <country_code>US</country_code>
                </stop>
            </stops>
            <start_time TZ="America/New_York">2015-05-28 09:20:20</start_time>
            <end_time TZ="America/New_York">2015-06-01 12:00:00</end_time>
            <equipments>
                <equipment>
                    <equipment_xid>77848</equipment_xid>
                    <equipment_type_xid/>
                    <equipment_type_name/>
                    <equipment_group_xid>28CV_VAN</equipment_group_xid>
                    <equipment_group_name>28FT_VAN</equipment_group_name>
                </equipment>
            </equipments>
            <remarks>
                <remark>
                    <remark_qual_gid>DELIVERY_INSTRUCTIONS_LINE_1</remark_qual_gid>
                    <remark_text>NONE</remark_text>
                </remark>
                <remark>
                    <remark_qual_gid>LTL_TOTAL_PALLET_COUNT</remark_qual_gid>
                    <remark_text>0</remark_text>
                </remark>
                <remark>
                    <remark_qual_gid>LTL_SOURCE_ADDRESS</remark_qual_gid>
                    <remark_text>400 PARK DRIVE</remark_text>
                </remark>
                <remark>
                    <remark_qual_gid>LTL_DEST_ADDRESS</remark_qual_gid>
                    <remark_text>1660 Georgesville Rd</remark_text>
                </remark>
            </remarks>
        </tender_record>

        <Type>TENDER</Type>
    </content>
</contents>
<Locale>
    <Language>en</Language>
    <Country>US</Country>
    <Variant/>
  </Locale>
 </notify>
```

and  xsl  used

```html
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
         <!--added code for key-->
         <xsl:key name="stops" match="contents/content" use="location_name" />
          <html>
          <body bgcolor="ffffff" vlink="gray" link="#0000cd" marginwidth="10" marginheight="10" leftmargin="10" topmargin="10">
   <table width="658" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
      <img alt="" src=""/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: top; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 16px; ">
      <xsl:value-of select="Contact[@ID='to']/Company"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: top; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; color: #000000;">
      Oracle Transportation Management<br/>
      Consolidated Pickup Notification
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="vertical-align: top; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">
      Please see below for a listing of Shipments due for Pickup, or that have been cancelled.
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
<!--Modifying the XSL code for consolidation Sequence below -->

      <xsl:for-each select="contents/content[count(. | key('stops', location_name)[1]) = 1]">
                                       <xsl:sort select="location_name" />
    <xsl:for-each select="key('stops',location_name)">
           <xsl:sort select="shipment_gid"/>


       
            <table width="658" cellpadding="3" style="border-spacing: 4px 0px;">
           
        
     <xsl:choose>
             <xsl:when test="subject='PICKUP_CANCEL'">
             <tr>
        <td style="color:#E26B0A;  font-size: 16px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-style:italic; font-weight: bold;" colspan="5">
         Pickup Cancel
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr style="background-color:#fabf8f; font-weight:bold; vertical-align: bottom; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12px; ">
        <td>Shipment ID</td>
        <td>Start Time</td>
        <td>Total Weight</td>
        <td>Total Volume</td>
        <td>Pallet Count</td>
       </tr>
       <tr style="background-color:#fde9d9; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12px; ">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="shipment_gid"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="tender_record/start_time"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="tender_record/total_weight"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="tender_record/total_volume"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="tender_record/remarks/remark[remark_qual_gid='LTL_TOTAL_PALLET_COUNT']/remark_text"/></td>
       </tr>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <tr>
        <td style="color:#366092;  font-size: 16px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-style:italic; font-weight: bold;" colspan="5">
         Pickup
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr style="background-color:#538dd5; font-weight:bold; vertical-align: bottom; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12px; ">
        <td>Shipment ID</td>
        <td>Start Time</td>
        <td>Total Weight</td>
        <td>Total Volume</td>
        <td>Pallet Count</td>
       </tr>
       <tr style="background-color:#c5d9f1; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12px; ">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="shipment_gid"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="tender_record/start_time"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="tender_record/total_weight"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="tender_record/total_volume"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="tender_record/remarks/remark[remark_qual_gid='LTL_TOTAL_PALLET_COUNT']/remark_text"/></td>
       </tr>
      </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
          
     <tr>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="5" style="background-color:#bfbfbf; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12px; ">
       Special Instructions: <xsl:value-of select ="tender_record/remarks/remark[remark_qual_gid='DELIVERY_INSTRUCTIONS_LINE_1']/remark_text"/>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
     
     <tr style="background-color:#f2f2f2;">
      <td colspan="5">
       <table  width="658" cellpadding="0" style="vertical-align: top; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12px;">
              <tr>
         <td>
          <span style="font-weight: bold">Pickup</span><br/>
          <xsl:value-of select="tender_record/stops/stop[stop_num=1]/location_name"/><br/>
          <xsl:value-of select="tender_record/remarks/remark[remark_qual_gid='LTL_SOURCE_ADDRESS']/remark_text"/><br/>
          <xsl:value-of select="tender_record/stops/stop[stop_num=1]/city"/><xsl:text>,&#160;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="tender_record/stops/stop[stop_num=1]/province_code"/><xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="tender_record/stops/stop[stop_num=1]/zip_code"/><xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="tender_record/stops/stop[stop_num=1]/country_code"/>
         </td>
         <td>
          <span style="font-weight: bold">Delivery</span><br/>
          <xsl:value-of select="tender_record/stops/stop[stop_num=2]/location_name"/><br/>
          <xsl:value-of select="tender_record/remarks/remark[remark_qual_gid='LTL_DEST_ADDRESS']/remark_text"/><br/>
          <xsl:value-of select="tender_record/stops/stop[stop_num=2]/city"/><xsl:text>,&#160;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="tender_record/stops/stop[stop_num=2]/province_code"/><xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="tender_record/stops/stop[stop_num=2]/zip_code"/><xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="tender_record/stops/stop[stop_num=2]/country_code"/>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
     <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="subject='PICKUP_CANCEL'">
       <tr style="background-color:#fabf8f; font-weight:bold; vertical-align: bottom; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12px;">
        <td>Line Item</td>
        <td>Haz Info</td>
        <td>Weight</td>
        <td>Handling Units</td>
        <td>Pallet Count</td>
       </tr>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <tr style="background-color:#538dd5; font-weight:bold; vertical-align: bottom; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12px;">
        <td>Line Item</td>
        <td>Haz Info</td>
        <td>Weight</td>
        <td>Handling Units</td>
        <td>Pallet Count</td>
       </tr>
      </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
     <xsl:for-each select="tender_record/remarks/remark[remark_qual_gid='LTL_LINE_INFO']">
      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="subject='PICKUP_CANCEL'">
        <tr style="background-color:#c5d9f1; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12px;">
         <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="remark_text" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
         </td>
        </tr>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
        <tr style="background-color:#fde9d9; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12px;">
         <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="remark_text" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
         </td>
        </tr>
       </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:for-each>
     <tr>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </xsl:for-each>
                       </xsl:for-each>
    <table width="658" cellpadding="2">
     <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12px; font-style: italic;">
                                 test      
         </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
                          </body>
                        </html>
                  </xsl:template>
                </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: For grouping in XSLT 1.0 see http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html and many, many examples here on SO.

Comment: hi I tried  it  but its not working could you please guide me on this

Comment: Post your attempt, then we may be able to guide you.

Comment: Hi michael  i updated  the xsl  which  i had tested ,but  its  not working its giving me the blank output

Comment: Please advice on this issue

Comment: Hi all please advice on this issue

Comment: Please advice on this  issue

Comment: Please advice on this issue